# Select Where With Multiple of the same

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table called 'matches' where I associate a **items** in the table "numbers" with an **item** in the table "letters" via there id.

So it looks like

```
number_id, letter_id 
1,10 
2,10
3,10
5,11
4,23
7,19 
1,19
3,64
```

now the user inputs an array of numbers, say 1,2,3
and I have to find the letter where all of it's numbers are 1,2,3, which would be 10. If they gave 1,7 it would give them 19, if they gave 3 it would give them and 64.

How can I do that?

I've been trying to write a recursive function for this but it always breaks.
is there some sort of:

```
SELECT letter_id WHERE **number_id***s* = 1,2,3. That would be perfect. :)
```

Comment: Could you provide more info on your table setup? Right now, there isn't any way to help you with your problem as the relation between both of your "items" does not seem to be injective (i.e. one-to-one). Please elaborate.

Comment: there really isn't more. It's quite random. http://i.tap.tc/172B1e0P2D2z1X342c0O in the screenshot, the fields are opposite, Letter_id is on the left, and Number_id is on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not work in all cases, but I tried with (1,2,3) and (1,7):

```
select distinct letter_id
from r r1
    inner join r r2 using (letter_id)
where r1.number_id in (1, 7)
    and r2.number_id in (1,7)
    and (r1.number_id  r2.number_id);
```

You'll have to be able to provide the `(1,7)` or `(1,2,3)` dynamically with some programming language.

Rocking baby at 3:30am...

*EDIT*: To complete the @Martin's answer, you can use `order by field()`

```
select letter_id 
from (
    select letter_id,
        group_concat(number_id order by field(number_id,2,1,3)) as numset
    from r 
    group by letter_id
    ) as Martin
where numset = '2,1,3';
```

Comment: +1 for the "order by" clause.  I didn't know that one. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Is numset a required term or is it the name of the field? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry to strip your right answer but I realized a new issue. If the array is 2,3,1,7 I want it to give both 10 and 19. Ideas?

Comment: @tap touch click:  you want 2,3,1,7 to give 10 and 19, but not 64 ? I no longer understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tap touch click: If you use my first example, you get the desired answer. @Martin has a good point though, why `64` does not come out as soon as `3` is in the list? My select won't work because it expects at least two numbers to match before returning any `letter_id`.

Comment: @Martin: `order by field()` is not well known. I found it once and was so useful that I tatoo it on my forehead :)

Comment: There will always be at least two

Comment: I'm using PHP, I'd like some help adding my own variables in. What's "Martin"?, What's numset? Thanks

Comment: @tap touch click: Martin is the name of the other user trying to help here. You can find his answer among the answers below. numset is the name of the column that represents the `group_concat()` of rows.  If you enter `(1,2)`, `10` will be returned, is that expected? I don't use PHP, but it should be easy for you to replace `(1,7)` in both places with the actual values you are requesting `(1,2,3)` or `(9,15)` etc...

Comment: so what does:  ) as Martin do?

Comment: using this exact code: select letter_id 
from (
    select letter_id,
        group_concat(number_id order by field(number_id,2,1,3)) as numset
    from matches
    group by letter_id
    ) as Martin
where numset = '2,1,3'; return nothing, even though the ids are right.

Comment: @tap touch click: Ok, your request is changing with each comment. Given the dataset you give in the OP, what are all the possibilities of requests and answers. We can't help you if you keep changing your mind. We are trying to help, not doing your job here.

Comment: Simple. The user gives an array of numbers. I want to find every letter where the letters numbers are ALL in the original array. I have found that I can sort numerically so that is no longer an issue. I'm using PHP for this as well, but my main purpose is trying to get the letter ids that are fully made up of numbers in the array

Comment: @tap touch click:   "select * from ( derived table expression ) as derived_table_name" is the form of select statement that allows a "derived table expression" to be used in place of a normal table.  It is one of the sub-query formats.

Comment: so what actions do I do with derived_table_name? I'm really not getting that part. The select doesn't seem to work at all, (returns nothing) even though its run (see: i.tap.tc/0t1F0A0h1X0w260V362H )

Answer (score 1):

If you can construct a string from your list of number_ids, you could use the following query:

```
select letter_id 
from (select letter_id, group_concat(number_id) as numset from `matches` 
      group by letter_id) as fred 
where numset = '1,2,3';
```

It is sensitive to order (eg. '2,1,3' would not match).

Comment: great, but how can I make it insensitive? :)

Comment: Look at my answer how to change yours.

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous comments made the problem more than what the OP was, here's another answer...

You may be able to work it out by having temporary tables:

```
create temporary table r_sum as
    select letter_id, count(*) as total
    from r 
    group by letter_id;
create temporary table r_count as
    select letter_id, count(*) as total
    from r
    where number_id in (1,2,3,7)
    group by letter_id;
select letter_id
from r_sum
    inner join r_count using (letter_id, total);
```

I think if this does not answer your question, I am not getting what you want and how to help you. If table is huge, you will have to create indexes on the temporary tables to help go faster. `r` is your original table in OP.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use IN statement for that.

try below query for that.

```
SELECT letter_id WHERE number_id IN (1,2,3)
```

you can pass array variable into the IN statement if you have.

Thanks.

Comment: It will return letter_id 10 and 64. It is not expected answer

Comment: Poonam Bhatt is right, I need something that requires all in the array.